# How do I drive through folders recursively in Windows Batch 'FOR /D /R' including root without '\.'?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way to recursively drive through folders in Windows Batch, and include the root folder you specify?

For example if I do:

```
FOR /D /R "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop" %%a in (*) do echo %%a
```

Results in:

```
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder1
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder2
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder2\SubFolder1
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder3
```

But no

```
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop
```

If I do:

```
FOR /D /R "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop" %%a in (.) do echo %%a
```

Results in:

```
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\.
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder1\.
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder2\.
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder2\SubFolder1\.
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder3\.
```

Which kinda works, but I don't want the `.\` in there.

Is there a way to get root folder and all subfolders to display like this:

```
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder1
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder2
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder2\Subfolder1
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Folder3
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I haven't figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Yep.  It is easy. `echo %%~fa`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one:

```
for /D /R "c:\users\jason\desktop" %%I in (.) do echo %%~fI >> out.txt
```

Comment: Because if this doesn't _actually_ answer the question at the top of the page, it's not going to help future visitors, which is the reason we keep content public in the first place.